# Live data sync in Lightning Communities

Tags: lightning, community

I have a custom community pages which is showing some content based on Account Status.
I need to update this section in my custom community page based on any server update on the account status field in Salesforce, in the same session without loading the whole page.
I tried platform event and LDS. Emp API is not working in community,so can't subscribe to platform event and LDS doesn't work with server load.
Any other possible workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use custom LWC  which uses the CometD library from the static resources. It should select the user's sessionId and connect to channel with Streaming API. Create handling events and exceptions similarly to EMP API. It is working in Communities. Check this repository, this example is working fine in Communities!
https://github.com/TheVishnuKumar/lwc-streaming-api